# Load responsive website in DIV that is smaller than the page

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries, viewport

We want to load a responsive website inside a DIV somewhere on a page. This div is smaller than the view port. The CSS that applies to this DIV (and thus responsive website) uses media queries to alter it's appearance.

The problem is that these media queries use the actual view port of the complete page rather than the width of the DIV that contains the responsive website. Due to this the responsive website may look all wrong.

Is there any way to alter the view port size that the @media queries use? Or any way we can influence the view port on a desktop device?

Note that due to certain limitations we CAN NOT use an iFrame. An iFrame would solve the problem.

Comment: Are you able to change the CSS of the site when it's viewed through this DIV? If so you could change the width of the container element to be the same size as the DIV.

Comment: We already thought about that. The width used in each media querie could be altered based on how much smaller the DIV is than the actual page. The problem is that the width of the DIV is dynamic; and does not necessarily depend on the width of the screen (ie: not always 50px smaller).